# Router returns 404 for encoded slash (%2F)

Tags: http, go

I have a simple http server and passing in a url such as:

`http://localhost:8000/test/bob%2Fvanderlen`

where `%2F` is the encoded form of `/`. I am using Gorilla mux for routing and have:

`router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true).UseEncodedPath()`

My route:

`router.NewRoute().Name("test").Methods("GET").Path("/test/{name}").Handler(
        f.middleware(appHandler(f.testHandler)),
    )`

When I hit the above url, I get a `404 Not Found`. Taking out the `%2F` gives me a `200` status.

From [this issue](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/issues/77) it seems like adding `UseEncodedPath()` is the answer but it still doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, typo. I'll update the question

Comment: @d681 See https://play.golang.org/p/buHCoJxxeyJ where %2F is handled correctly.  How are you testing the URLs? Is the middleware, apphandler or testhandler returning the 404?

Comment: Turns out I had an outdated version of Gorilla mux. Works now

Comment: mark it as solved then